# Why does a user get prompted for password under AIX?

Tags: password, aix

Users get prompted for password, and according to the `lsuser -f username` output:

```
expires=0
maxexpired=-1
maxage=13
```

users shouldn't be prompted for changing password.

Why does he has a change password prompt when logging in?

P.S.:

1. According to maxage+last password update, his password expired at:

   ```
   Mon Sep 27 16:26:32 CEST 2010
   ```

   but the `maxexpired=-1` should take care of this, and the user shouldn't be prompted to change the pasaword.
2. ```
   oslevel -s
   6100-02-02-0849
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `maxexpired` attribute is the number of weeks after password expiration that a user is allowed to login (and change their password). A setting of `-1` disables this restriction. Setting `maxexpired=-1` prevents account lockout due to expired passwords; a new password must still be set once the `maxage` weeks have elapsed since the last password change.

`maxage` is the attribute that determines the password expiration. Your example has passwords expire 13 weeks after they are set. If you wish to have an account with no password expiration, set `maxage=0`.

Since you included the `expires` attribute: `expires` is the date when the account expires, not its password. Setting this to `0` means the account does not expire. `maxage` will still determine the password expiration.

Comment: p.s.: the user was prompted to change password because it's default shell was the passwd's binary... :)